# 2nd Call to strtok() returns null

Tags: c, char, delimiter, strtok

I'm at the top of a while loop in the client file for a client/server communication.  The client gets user input (input) and I need to strtok it into cmd and cmd2 for my ifs to work.

Say the user puts in "get lname" (this is a good command for the program).
Using the following code, cmd = "get" (yay!), but cmd2 = "(null)"

input is a char input[30]
cmd and cmd2 are char* initialized to NULL.

A little help here?  Thanks!

```
    /*Until the user exits the program*/
    while(cmdNum != 7)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a command: ");
        scanf("%30s", input);

        cmd = strtok(input, " ");
printf("cmd: %s\n", cmd);

        if(strcmp(cmd, "get") == 0)
        {
            cmd2 = strtok(NULL, "\0");
printf("cmd2: %s\n", cmd2);

            pstatus = print(cmd, sockfd);

            if(pstatus == 1)
            {
                printf("Error printing\n");
            }
        }
        else if(strcmp(cmd, "put") == 0)..... etc, etc....
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second `strtok` call should also use a single space for it's delimiter argument, not `"\0"`, which , if you think about it, is simply an empty string.

And more importantly, you need to read the in entire line, which `scanf` with `%s` does not do. It stops at the first space. Try `fgets` instead, but remember that it leaves the newline in, so add that as a delimiter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char input[50];

    printf("Please enter a command: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);

    char *cmd = strtok(input, " \t\n");
    printf("cmd: [%s]\n", cmd);

    if (strcmp(cmd, "get") == 0) {
        char *cmd2 = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        printf("cmd2: [%s]\n", cmd2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't do it :(

I switched it to cmd2 = strtok(NULL, " ");

Still returning (null)

Comment: @airvector222 I'm not sure what's going wrong! I've added a runnable example to my "answer". But, as you say, it prints `(null)`.

Comment: Try printing out `input` before processing. This has nothing to do with `strtok()`, and everything to do with `scanf()`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths  Arrrrgggghhh!!! Focusing on the wrong spot. Of course, the `%s` option only reads up to the first space! I'm fixing the above code now.

Answer (score 0):

After thefirst call to strtok pass NULL for the first parameter. The function stores a static var to remember where it left off.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Comment: Yes sir, that's what I'm doing.  No dice :(